# Does this series converge or diverge and by which test?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1} \sin(1/n^3)$$

I tried to apply the divergence test. I know $\lim_{n\to \infty}$ is 0 for $b_n$ but I don't think $b_n$ is decreasing. any ideas on how I can test this series?

Comment: If you can prove that sin(x)<x for x>0 that might do the trick.

Comment: Try the Limit Comparison Test against $ \ \frac{1}{n^3} \ $ : the series is absolutely convergent.

Answer (score 2):

Since $\sin(x)$ is increasing for $0 < x < \pi/2$ and $0 < \frac{1}{n^3} < \frac{\pi}{2}$ for all $n$, then $\sin(1/n^3)$ is decreasing in $n$. So since $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} \sin(1/n^3) = 0$, by the alternating series test, $\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1}\sin(1/n^3)$ converges.

Answer (score 1):

Since $|\sin(x)|\leq |x|$ for all $x$,

$$\left|\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1}\sin(1/n^3)\right
|\leq\sum_{n=1}^\infty|\sin(1/n^3)|\leq\sum_{n=1}^\infty 1/n^3=\zeta(3)<\infty.$$

Comment: Your answer is still a little strange, because you start by taking the absolute value of a series you haven't proved converges. It's better to say $| (-1)^{n+1}\sin(1/n^3)|=\sin(1/n^3)\le 1/n^3$ and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty 1/n^3<\infty.$ Thus the series converges absolutely, hence converges.

Comment: @zhw Of course if one starts from right to left, then the logic flows fine.

Comment: @Dr.MV Respectfully, one needs to say that absolute convergence implies convergence somewhere in the argument, and if one does, I would think the quantity $\left|\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1}\sin(1/n^3)\right
|$ never needs to be mentioned at all given the question.

Comment: @zhw. Yes, the left-hand side is quite unnecessary.  As you said, simply stating that AC $\implies$ is sufficient.